# What if the kafka leader crashes before committing the offset to zookeeper?

Tags: design, apache-kafka

I'm not encountering any issue in prod or anything, I'm just reading about Kafka and I'm curious about this case.

As I understand,

- A producer sends messages to the leader.
- The replicas copy the messages and inform the leader about how far they have read up. Let's say I have sent 6 messages to the leader and the replicas have read up to 4. (`acks=all`).
- The leader will write `commit_offset=4` to zookeeper and then return `http=200` to the first 4 producer requests.

Now what if the leader crashes AFTER it commits to zookeeper and BEFORE it returns 200?

The producer will want to send the first 4 messages again. Is that expected? Something that kafka handles for us? or is there something that I missed? Or is it when we need to build in deduplication into our application?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

Comment: not sure to understand the negative votes... if you do so please give some feedback so that I understand and know for next time

Comment: meh, i guess its because it sounds like something specific to kafka you might ask them about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the advice seems to be to check the last commited transaction before resending in these circumstances.

If you think about it, in the case of a crash or network failure, you wont get an error response at all. So you will be able to detect the "that message may or may not have been written" state and know to check.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I was directly involved with Kafka but the only big issues we experienced were related to reprocessing issues.  The issues we had with this were pretty significant.  There was one situation where the offset was reset and we reprocessed weeks, if not months, worth of old messages.  The systems that handled these were robust enough to ignore duplicates, but the load of that reprocessing caused delays for new events.

I was never certain about the exact cause.  There was an article from LinkedIn (where it was developed) which described a similar issue but only said it was due to a 'server getting wedged' but I couldn't find any clear explanation of what that means.  I found some evidence that the ZK cluster was unstable at that time and likely failed to respond to requests fast enough for Kafka.  We ended up keeping a backup offset elsewhere and if the offset Kafka was using was before that, we knew something went wrong.

In any event, the design of Kafka has a strong bias toward resending messages over not sending them.  If you use it, make sure you follow the configuration advice for ZK and if reprocessing is an issue, you will probably want to implement some sort of duplicate processing protections.